# Access denied for a semaphore in a normal application, when it was first created by a service

Tags: c++, ms-access, semaphore

I create a global semaphore in a library that is used by a normal application and a service.
If I run my normal application before the service, every thing comes fine, but if I change the order (I mean, running service before application), I will get access denied error in normal application when I trying to create or open the existed semaphore.
I set SEMAPHORE_ALL_ACCESS during semaphore creation, but it doesn't solve the problem. In a ridiculous way, I also add SYNCHRONIZE and SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE (by | operand), but it doesn't' solve the problem too.

Do you have any idea?
I'm using windows 8.1 (x64) and run both the 32bit version of service and application.

Comment: You will need to lower the integrity if you want to access a semaphore created by a service in a "normal" application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to lower the integrity level of the resource, try something like this to create.

```
 SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
 SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

 sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
 sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
 sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;

 if(InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd,  SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
 {
     if(SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, (PACL) NULL, FALSE))   
     {
         PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;   

         // Try to lower Integrity, if OS is Vista or higher        
         if(bIsOSVistaOrLater)
         {
             if(ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor("S:(ML;;NW;;;LW)", SDDL_REVISION_1, &pSD, NULL))
             {
                  PACL pSacl = NULL;
                  BOOL fSaclPresent = FALSE;
                  BOOL fSaclDefaulted = FALSE;
                  if(GetSecurityDescriptorSacl(pSD, &fSaclPresent, &pSacl, &fSaclDefaulted) )
                  {
                      if(SetSecurityDescriptorSacl(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, TRUE, pSacl, FALSE))
                      {
                         ... = CreateSemaphore(&sa, 1, 1, "xpto");

                      }                      
                  }              
              }
         }          
         else
         {
            ... = CreateSemaphore(&sa, 1, 1, "xpto");           
         }
     }
 }
```

you can read more about this: [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/11/10/access-denied-on-a-mutex.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes I found that my problem is related to windows security descriptor